# Why is my program ignoring the switch statement?

Tags: c++, xcode, switch-statement

My program is ignoring the switch statement. When I run it, I enter my input and it just skips to the default which says "Invalid response". Whatever I enter it goes to default, skipping the cases of the switch statement entirely. I've checked the code and it looks completely fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


void ave();
void lar();
void sma();
void med();
void sorta();
void sortd();
int n;
int n1;
int n2;
int n3;
int n4;
int n5;
int n6;
int n7;
int n8;
int n9;
int n10;
int list[10] = {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10};
int av;
int la;
int sm;
int me;
int sa;
int sd;
bool wayToSort(int i, int j) { return i > j; };

int main()
{

int c;
char q;

cout<< "Enter the first integer";
cin>> n1;
cout<< "Enter the second integer";
cin>> n2;
cout<< "Enter the third integer";
cin>> n3;
cout<< "Enter the fourth integer";
cin>> n4;
cout<< "Enter the fifth integer";
cin>> n5;
cout<< "Enter the sixth integer";
cin>> n6;
cout<< "Enter the seventh integer";
cin>> n7;
cout<< "Enter the eighth integer";
cin>> n8;
cout<< "Enter the ninth integer";
cin>> n9;
cout<< "Enter the tenth integer";
cin>> n10;

cout<< "1 - If you wish to find the average of the integers, press 1 \n";
cout<< "2 - If you wish to find the largest integer, press 2 \n";
cout<< "3 - If you wish to find the smallest integer, press 3 \n";
cout<< "4 - If you wish to find the median number, press 4 \n";
cout<< "5 - If you wish to sort the integers in ascending order, press 5 \n";
cout<< "6 - If you wish to sort the integers in descending order, press 6 \n";

//c = getchar();

cin>> c;

switch (c)
{
        case '1':
        ave();
        break;

        case '2':
        lar();
        break;

        case '3':
        sma();
        break;

        case '4':
        med();
        break;

        case '5':
        sorta();
        break;

        case '6':
        sortd();
        break;

    default:
        cout<< "Invaid choice";

        return 0;
}

void ave();
{
av = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6 + n7 + n8 + n9 + n10) /10;
cout<< "The average of the numbers is " << av << endl;


}


void lar();
{
la = n1;
if (n2 > la)
    la = n2;
else if (n3 > la)
    la = n3;
else if (n4 > la)
    la = n4;
else if (n5 > la)
    la = n5;
else if (n6 > la)
    la = n6;
else if (n7 > la)
    la = n7;
else if (n8 > la)
    la = n8;
else if (n9 > la)
    la = n9;
else if (n10 > la)
    la = n10;

cout<< "The largest integer is " << la << endl;


}



void sma();
{
    sm = n1;
    if (n2 < sm)
        sm = n2;
    else if (n3 < sm)
        sm = n3;
    else if (n4 < sm)
        sm = n4;
    else if (n5 < sm)
        sm = n5;
    else if (n6 < sm)
        sm = n6;
    else if (n7 < sm)
        sm = n7;
    else if (n8 < sm)
        sm = n8;
    else if (n9 < sm)
        sm = n9;
    else if (n10 < sm)
        sm = n10;




}

void med();
{
    sort(list, list + 10);

    for (size_t i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        me = 0.5 * (list[n/2] + list[n/2-1]);



        }


void sorta();
{
    sort(list, list + 10);

    cout<< "The sorted array looks like this " << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        cout<< list[i] << " ";



}

void sortd();
{
    vector<int> intVec = { n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10};
    sort(intVec.begin(), intVec.end(), wayToSort);

    for (int i : intVec)
        cout<< i << " ";




}



cout<< "\n Quit (y/n)";
cin>> q;
q = getchar();
```

}

Comment: c is an integer. do not use quotations

Comment: ...or make `c` a `char` rather than an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a lot to be refactored and many errors also. Correcting and refactoring it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    array<int, 10> arr;
    int c;
    cout << "Enter all the elements\n";
    for (int & i : arr) cin >> i;
    cout<< "1 - If you wish to find the average of the integers, press 1 \n";
    cout<< "2 - If you wish to find the largest integer, press 2 \n";
    cout<< "3 - If you wish to find the smallest integer, press 3 \n";
    cout<< "4 - If you wish to find the median number, press 4 \n";
    cout<< "5 - If you wish to sort the integers in ascending order, press 5 \n";
    cout<< "6 - If you wish to sort the integers in descending order, press 6 \n";
    cin >> c;
    switch (c) {
    case 1:
        cout << "The average of the numbers is " << accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0) / arr.size() << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "The largest integer is " << *max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end()) << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "The smallest integer is " << *min_element(arr.begin(), arr.end()) << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        nth_element(arr.begin(), arr.begin() + arr.size() / 2, arr.end());
        cout << "The median number is " << arr[arr.size() / 2] << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
        for (int i : arr) cout << i << " ";
        cout << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), greater<int>());
        for (int i : arr) cout << i << " ";
        cout << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cerr << "Invaid choice\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See <kbd>[LIVE VERSION](http://ideone.com/iUozBd)</kbd>.

Comment: My compiler won't recognize <bits/stdc++.h>

Comment: It says "bits/stdc++.h file not found"

Comment: Thanks! Since Xcode doesn't have gcc and it could't recognize the <bit/stdc++.h> I used other libraries and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually calling a function here:

```
    case '1':
    void ave();
    break;
```

In fact you're just declaring a function.

It should instead be:

```
    case '1':
        ave();   // call function `ave()`
        break;
```

Ditto for all the other cases in your `switch`.

There may be other problems too, but you haven't shown us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so it's hard to tell.

Comment: I first tried it without the void and it gave me errors saying " ave( ); referenced from _main.

Comment: As I said above, there may be other problems too, but you haven't shown us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please do that and then we can help you fix any other problems. (FWIW it sounds like `ave()` is either not defined/implemented, or it's in another source file and you're not linking this file.)

Comment: @HamzahHashmi: You must have declared `ave` prior to the switch, and usually you would declare it outside the calling function (i.e. before main)